# Python extract data from a semi-structured .xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, reference

I have a .xlsx file which looks as the attached file. What is the most common way to extract the different data parts from this excel file in Python?

Ideally there would be a method that is defined as :

`pd.read_part_csv(columns=['data1', 'data2','data3'], rows=['val1', 'val2', 'val3'])`
and returns an iterator over `pandas` dataframes which hold the values in the given table.

[image: table]

Comment: always there are just va1,val2 and val3 ?

Comment: Not exactly the answer you're looking for, but usually when I'm working with data like this I'll throw the data file into a numpy array and then splice it directly. using something like `data=pd.read_excel(path).to_numpy()` then `array1=data[5:8,1:4]` and `array2=data[10:13, 2:5]` to grab the data

Comment: Well, depending on how complex this is you have some work to do. Since the columns are in different columns of the excel file, and there are different number of spaces... but you may just want to start out by removing blank rows and work from there.

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar : No there might also be val4, val5 ,... and data4, data5, ...

Comment: @MichaelGreen : OK that's a good tip, if nothing concrete is replied I will just use your method.

Comment: @MattR : The issue is that the excel is not provided by myself so I have to write a program which is able to work with this type of excel directly.

Comment: What you might be able to do is write a script which goes around the excel file and marks where cells with numbers are, and using that delineation automate the array generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution with pylightxl that might be a good fit for your project if all you are doing is reading. I wrote the solution in terms of rows but you could just as well have done it in terms of columns. See docs for more info on pylightxl https://pylightxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

```
import pylightxl
db = pylightxl.readxl('Book1.xlsx')
# pull out all the rowIDs where data groups start
keyrows = [rowID for rowID, row in enumerate(db.ws('Sheet1').rows,1) if 'val1' in row]

# find the columnIDs where data groups start (like in your example, not all data groups start in col A)
keycols = []
for keyrow in keyrows:
    # add +1 since python index start from 0
    keycols.append(db.ws('Sheet1').row(keyrow).index('val1') + 1)

# define a dict to hold your data groups
datagroups = {}
# populate datatables
for tableIndex, keyrow in enumerate(keyrows,1):
    i = 0
    # data groups: keys are group IDs starting from 1, list: list of data rows (ie: val1, val2...)
    datagroups.update({tableIndex: []})
    while True:
        # pull out the current group row of data, and remove leading cells with keycols
        datarow = db.ws('Sheet1').row(keyrow + i)[keycols[tableIndex-1]:]
        # check if the current row is still part of the datagroup
        if datarow[0] == '':
            # current row is empty and is no longer part of the data group
            break
        datagroups[tableIndex].append(datarow)
        i += 1


print(datagroups[1])
print(datagroups[2])
```

---

```
[[1, 2, 3, ''], [4, 5, 6, ''], [7, 8, 9, '']]
[[9, 1, 4], [2, 4, 1], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Note that output of table 1 has extra '' on it, that is because the size of the sheet data is larger than your group size. You can easily remove these with list.remove('') if you like